# Every Nth Char in Source Outputs N

Tags: code-challenge, source-layout

Heavily inspired by [Hello, World! (Every other character)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/128496/65836)

Write a program that outputs `1`. When the first, third, fifth, etc. chars are removed, it outputs `2`. When all chars where their (`1`-based) index in the source, mod `N`, are not `0`, are removed, it should output `N`.

This is [code-challenge](/questions/tagged/code-challenge). The winner is the program that works with the largest `N`, while working for all `n < N` (obviously, to run up to `N`, it has to be at least `N` characters long). If there is a tie, the winner is the shortest answer that reaches the largest `N`. Your program must at least work up to `N=2`, since I don't think any languages will struggle with simply printing `1`. **To prevent programs extending infinitely, your program may not be longer than 1024 bytes**.

## Example

Examples are based off of this sample program: `abc123def456ghi789`.

For the program to work for `N=1`, `abc123def456ghi789` should output `1`.

For the program to work for `N=2`, `b13e46h79` should output `2`.

For the program to work for `N=3`, `c3f6i9` should output `3`.

For the program to work for `N=4`, `1e67` should output `4`.

For the program to work for `N=5`, `24i` should output `5`.

For the program to work for `N=6`, `369` should output `6`.

For the program to work for `N=7`, `dh` should output `7`.

etc.

The highest `N` this program could work for is its length, `18`.

Remember that the winner will be the question that works for the largest `N` that also works for all smaller `n`s where `n<N`.

This is not a duplicate of [Run the Nth characters to get N](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36397/run-the-nth-characters-to-get-n). That challenge take the first char and the each `N`th char after that, while mine takes the `N`th char and each `N`th char after that. In addition, that is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), and only is for `N <= 16`

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/13122#13122)

Comment: [Very closely related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/36397/8478) (Same challenge as code golf with fixed `N`.)

Comment: Is there any reason to assume that scoring by `N` doesn't just turn this into an exercise in patience for who can be bothered to add the most numbers? I don't see any natural upper limit.

Comment: @MartinEnder that challenge also always starts with the first character. Personally, I doubt that someone can go near infinite with it - I personally can't see any way you'd implement this infinitely. That's partly because of the difference in which chars get removed from my challenge and Helka's. If the answers prove me wrong I may need to set a byte cap or something. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing as I already said, it's not. That challenge take the first char and the each `N`th char after that, while mine takes the `N`th char and each `N`th char after that. In addition, that is [tag:code-golf], and only is for `N <= 16`

Comment: @StepHen but the underlying challenge is the same: output N from code made from the Nth chars. The fact that it's code golf doesn't count as I could make a Hello World challenge, where the winning criteria was fastest code but it'd still be closed as a dupe. And the `N <= 16` is the *minimum* requirement so that people don't just submit a 1 byte answer. I could easily find an answer from that thread and answer it here, therefore this is a dupe.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing from the other challenge: `Your program does not have to work for N = 17 or above.` If you want, I can bump up my minimum (currently `N = 2`)

Comment: @StepHen it doesn't *have* to but answers can be adapted to do so.

Comment: @MartinEnder thanks for the input about the upper limit, I'm added a byte cap.