# Number of characters skipped determines code printed

Tags: code-golf, radiation-hardening

Write a program which, when every nth character is skipped, it prints n. For example, if every 2nd character is skipped, it prints 2.

## Example

**n=0**

```
foobar
```

Output:

```
0
```

**n=1**

```
foa
```

Output:

```
1
```

**n=2**

```
fobr
```

Output:

```
2
```

## Rules

- If n=0 (no characters are skipped), 0 must be returned.
- Must print to STDOUT.
- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- The first character is never skipped.
- Obviously, it doesn't need to work for more characters than the code has (e.g. if your code is 11 characters long, it doesn't need to work for every 11th character)

## Scoring

This is *code golf*, so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen a challenge like this before, but I have to question the "code golf" aspect: Fewer characters (say, a 2 byte program) would never need to output `3` because there would be no 3rd character. I'm pretty sure the older challenge was to output *as many different results* as when programs got longer there were more collisions to deal with. Shorter just gives an advantage to languages that can output `0` with 0 or 1 bytes (and is not challenging).

Comment: How is **n=1** "fobr"? If I understand the challenge it should be "foa" because you remove each character in parenthesis: `f(o)o(b)a(r)`

Comment: Ooooh, this is a radiation-hardening type problem. I thought it was printing every n characters of the input or something.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf SE! We have a [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) where you can post a potential challenge and get meaningful feedback before posting it to Main, which can help clear up questions such as the ones currently in the comments.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this challenge a bit better.Are you portraying that `foobar` is the theoretical source code, and skipping every character of the original source code, `foobar`, resulting in `foa`, would print a different result?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36397/run-the-nth-characters-to-get-n?rq=1 except this one lacks a minimum length

Comment: @AlienAtSystem Those are actually pretty different.  This one is remove every \$kn+1\$th character while that one is keep every \$k\$th character.

Comment: Still, I think a minimum length requirement would improve this challenge as well

Comment: @AlienAtSystem That might be the one I was thinking of.

Answer (score 10):

## Polyglot, 1 byte

```
0
```

[Try it in Retina](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/f4P9/AA)

[Try it in Jelly](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/g/38A)

[Try it in 05AB1E](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f4P9/AA)

[Try it in Husk](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3@D/fwA)

[Try it in ///](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/3@D/fwA)

[Try it in GolfScript](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/3@D/fwA)

[Try it in BrainGolf](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@//f4P9/AA)

[Try it in Pyth](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3@D/fwA)

[Try it in Japt](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3@D/fwA)

[Try it in ink](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v/f4P9/AA)

[Try it in PHP](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/f4P9/AA)

[Try it in Brachylog](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/3@D///9RAA)

[Try it in MATL](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3@D/fwA)

[Try it in Keg](https://tio.run/##y05N///f4P9/AA)

[Try it in Carrot](https://tio.run/##S04sKsov@f/f4P9/AA)

Comment: Definitely not Lua, Turing Machine Code, or Emoji

Comment: You can add m4 too.

Comment: You can add [Jamal](http://peter.verhas.com/progs/perl/jamal/) too, though without TIO link.